# Why append-map instead of map in recursive cartesian product function?

Tags: dictionary, recursion, racket

Cartesian product function takes a list of lists and returns a list of tuples with an element from the first list in the first position, element from second in second position, etc. As shown below:

```
((1 2 3)) -> ((1) (2) (3))
((1 2) (3 4)) -> ((1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4))
```

I'm looking at some of my old code and can't figure out why it's append-map in the outer loop rather than just map? Could someone with more experience in Racket explain this to me?

```
(define cartesian-product
  (lambda (s)
    (if (null? s)
        '(())
        (append-map (lambda (el1)
                      (map (lambda (el2)
                             (cons el1 el2))
                           (cartesian-product (cdr s))))
                    (car s)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to *flatten* the list returned by the recursive call to `cartesian-product`, otherwise you'll get a ton of undesired sublists, see what happens if we don't use `append-map`:

```
(define cartesian-product
  (lambda (s)
    (if (null? s)
        '(())
        (map (lambda (el1)
               (map (lambda (el2)
                      (cons el1 el2))
                    (cartesian-product (cdr s))))
             (car s)))))

(cartesian-product '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
=> '(((1 (4)) (1 (5)) (1 (6))) ((2 (4)) (2 (5)) (2 (6))) ((3 (4)) (3 (5)) (3 (6))))
```

Compare it with the result of flattenning the list:

```
(define cartesian-product
  (lambda (s)
    (if (null? s)
        '(())
        (append-map (lambda (el1)
                      (map (lambda (el2)
                             (cons el1 el2))
                           (cartesian-product (cdr s))))
                    (car s)))))

(cartesian-product '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
=> '((1 4) (1 5) (1 6) (2 4) (2 5) (2 6) (3 4) (3 5) (3 6))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I somewhat understand? Does it need to be flattened because the map produces several lists?

Comment: @szhongren that's right! and we're only interested in the top-level lists.